# Custom hour range in full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use full calendar and I have the following view:

[image]
But I want to make it show only the hours that I tell it to, something like this: (Sorry for the crummy design, I did it with paint to show the result I want to achieve)
[image]

That is, what I want is for them to leave only the hours that I tell them. I have looked at the documentation but I don't see how to get it, do you know how?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendario1');
            var taller = '<?php echo $tare;?>'
            var user = '<?php echo $ctrl_user;?>'
            var userfiltro = '0'
  calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'local',
    locale: 'es',
    views:{
      resourceTimelineMonth:{
        duration: { days:7 },
        slotMinTime: "09:00:00",
        slotMaxTime: "20:00:00",
      },
      resourceTimelineWeek:{
        duration: { days:7 },
        slotMinTime: "09:00:00",
        slotMaxTime: "20:00:00",
      },
      resourceTimelineDay:{
        duration: { days:1 },
        slotMinTime: "09:00:00",
        slotMaxTime: "19:00:00",
        text: "Dia",
      }
    },
  //let calendario1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('Calendario1'), {   
    
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
    },
    editable: true,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Trabajadores',
    resources: 'test.php?accion=listarempleados&taller=' + taller + '&user=' + user + '&user_filtro=' +userfiltro,
    //resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
   events: 'test.php?accion=listar&taller=' + taller + '&user=' + user + '&user_filtro=' +userfiltro,
dateClick: function(info) {
                console.log("ES "+JSON.stringify(info));
                 limpiarFormulario();
                    $('#BotonAgregar').show();
                    $('#BotonModificar').hide();
                    $('#BotonOt').hide();
                    $('#BotonBorrar').hide();
                    $('#iduser').val(info.resource.id);
                    if (info.allDay) {
                        $('#FechaInicio').val(info.dateStr);
                        $('#FechaFin').val(info.dateStr);
                    } else {
                        let fechaHora = info.dateStr.split("T");
                        var horainit = fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5);
                        var horafin = (parseInt(horainit) + parseInt(1))+":00";
                        $('#FechaInicio').val(fechaHora[0]);
                        $('#FechaFin').val(fechaHora[0]);
                        $('#HoraInicio').val(fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5));
                        $('#HoraFin').val(horafin);
                    }
                    $("#FormularioEventos").modal();
                },
                eventClick: function(info) {
                    console.log("EL RES ES "+JSON.stringify(info.event));
                    console.log("LA HORA ES "+moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#BotonModificar').show();
                    if (info.event.extendedProps.idtra != 0) {
                        if (info.event.extendedProps.tipo_parte != 0) {
                            $('#BotonOt').attr("href", "./modifica_parte_contado.php?id=" + info.event.extendedProps.idtra).show();
                        } else {
                            $('#BotonOt').attr("href", "./modifica_parte_cia.php?id=" + info.event.extendedProps.idtra).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#BotonOt').hide();
                    }
                    $('#BotonBorrar').show();
                    $('#BotonAgregar').hide();
                    $('#Codigo').val(info.event.id);
                    $('#iduser').val(info.event.extendedProps.iduser);
                    $('#idtra').val(info.event.idtra);
                    $('#Titulo').val(info.event.title);
                    $('#Descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#FechaFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#HoraInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#HoraFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.event.textColor);
                    $("#FormularioEventos").modal();
                },
                eventResize: function(info) {
                    $('#Codigo').val(info.event.id);

                    $('#Titulo').val(info.event.title);
                    $('#iduser').val(info.event.extendedProps.iduser);
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#FechaFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#HoraInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#HoraFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.event.textColor);
                    $('#Descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
                    let registro = recuperarDatosFormulario();
                    modificarRegistro(registro);
                    
                },
                eventDrop: function(info) {
                    $('#Codigo').val(info.event.id);
                    $('#Titulo').val(info.event.title);
                    $('#iduser').val(info.event.extendedProps.iduser);
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#FechaFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                    $('#HoraInicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#HoraFin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm"));
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.event.textColor);
                    $('#Descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
                    let registro = recuperarDatosFormulario();
                    modificarRegistro(registro);
                },
                drop: function(info) {
                    limpiarFormulario();
                    $('#ColorFondo').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.colorfondo);
                    $('#ColorTexto').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.colortexto);
                    $('#Titulo').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.titulo);
                    let fechaHora = info.dateStr.split("T");
                    $('#FechaInicio').val(fechaHora[0]);
                    $('#FechaFin').val(fechaHora[0]);
                    $('#tiempocita').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.tiempocita);
                    if (info.allDay) { //verdadero si el calendario esta en vista de mes
                        $('#HoraInicio').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.horainicio);
                        $('#HoraFin').val(info.draggedEl.dataset.horafin);
                    } else {
                        $('#HoraInicio').val(fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5));
                        $('#HoraFin').val(moment(fechaHora[1].substring(0, 5)).add(1, 'hours'));
                    }
                    let registro = recuperarDatosFormulario();
                    agregarEventoPredefinido(registro);
                }
  });

  calendario1.render();
```

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible in FullCalendar. The documentation describing the time axis settings include a `slotMinTime` and `slotMaxTime` pair of settings, but nothing that looks like it supports non-contiguous time slots. You could try using the [`slotLaneContent`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slot-render-hooks) content injection input to try to remove lanes for certain hours, but I'm not sure this would actually result in the space being collapsed.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+fullcalendar+custom+range+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Agreed. You can set the minimum time, and you can set slot duration, but you cannot exclude random time ranges. I think that would be confusing for users anyway, especially if they are not looking as closely as they should be. The whole point of a consistent visual display in a calendar is that it conveys information in a simpler way than just text. I see no reason to provide such a feature. If you want to make certain sections of time unavailable for selection (for example), there are other ways to do that.

Comment: Maybe I'm not putting it right. What I really want is for each day to have 5 "blocks" of time, I don't know if I explain myself...

Comment: Ok. Well, for example, you could mark the areas which are not part of any of the blocks, by putting Background Events into them, or something like that. Then it's clear to the user which time is available, and which is not. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events